# Magento multi-site pricing and per group pricing

Tags: magento

So, the site we are working on right now is going to be Multisite and we are going to have different pricing for each website. The issue comes when one of those sites needs to have two different price lists.

There is going to be the price list for one site, and another price list for the other and then there will be a price list  based on the customer group for the second site. I am not sure the best way to set this up since the pricing will be per website. The only other option that I see out of the box is to use the tiered pricing functionality and set if customer group A qty 1 and above use this price. (Thank you Joseph Mastey from one of your other answers!)

I'm concerned about this since I am doing a nightly price update as well and I assume programmatically saving this per product could be a pain. If anyone has any tips on setting the tiered pricing programmatically that would be huge or if you have another suggestion I would appreciate all that come my way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the mention :)

Having looked at this before, you're exactly correct. The tiered prices seem to be the only easy way to accomplish this. I have thought about trying to use multiple store views to the same effect, but I haven't had success yet.

Also, yes, updating tier prices can be a pain, I'm not sure the APIs even support it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about store views as well but when I ran across your tiered pricing concept, I thought that would work out better.

Answer (score 2):

The API does support updating tier pricing.

http://prattski.com/2010/03/04/magento-import-tier-pricing-using-api/

Answer (score 1):

If there is a simple percentage reduction for one customer group then you can use a Catalog Price Rule.

Comment: Yeah, its not percentage or flat dollar amount across the board, its a whole different price list at the product level that is different on probably a few thousand products.